# Is it "dog and cat'S communication skills" OR "dog'S and cat'S communication skills"?

Tags: grammar, possessives

Should it be dog's and cat's skills because the possession is separate ownership and not shared?

I have a theory:

Despite the fact that dog or cat's communication skills are not shared, it's the same way of communication: non-verbal, based on emotions. They (animals) may have different means of communication but somehow it's a "human-animal" interaction

Answer (score 0):

Either both need to be possessive, or neither!

- Dog's and cat's communication skills.
- Dog and cat communication skills

If something is jointly owned and you are stressing the separate identify of the owners it is normal to use two possessives, either nouns or pronouns, for example "*the house is yours and mine*". The only time you wouldn't do that is if you are grouping the owners together as a unit, for example "*that is John and Jane's son*". However, your example doesn't warrant that - cats and dogs are not a unit, they don't communicate with one another (as far as I know!) and so their individual skills are being grouped together by this statement.

My latter example doesn't require possessives because it uses 'dog' and 'cat' as noun modifiers in much the same way as we say '*dog food*'.

Comment: Thank you very much!